# Magento simple product images

Tags: magento

I have  a question regarding Magento simple product images as Configurable product variations.
So as described in developing guide, it is necessary to upload images for each product variation (Simple product) for using Colorswatch extension to be able to change product image on front end by clicking color sample. Each product has also size attribute, which makes a lot of product variations and a lot of same image uploads.
If i have 5 sizes and 3 colors of one product, and 5 images of each color i have to upload 5 times (5 sizes) whole set of images(5 images in this case) for each color.
Question is, is there any way to upload just one set of images of one color for all sizes of that color variation?? 
It is crucial to use Configurable products with Simple products for variations because of inventory control.

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you have to upload images for each product variations.
However, you can customize Magento to synchronize images for each simple product of the same color and different size (inside of the configurable product).

Comment: And how to do that? Is there possibility to just assign same image urls to another simple products of same color and different size?

Answer (score 1):

As [Roman Snitko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/473281/roman-snitko) suggested, We can show multiple images/single images under a product with different attributes(colors,sizes).

In Magnto-2.1.8 you can do this by following below steps.

1. Go to `Products > Catalog`
2. Select a product to edit.
3. `Content > Configurations > Edit Configurations`.
4. Select/Create required attributes according to your requirement.
5. Create attribute values.
6. Select if you want to use different images for the same product or single image to represent the product with different attribute values.(We can use different prices and quantities for the same product with different attribute values).
7. Save configuration changes.